# Jquery text style and loading

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, slide, pjax

I have a problem with pjax animation text and links in the content box are changed to bold during the animation, which is very disturbing. Another problem is that the new content is sometimes not loaded yet when the animation is already over and the content changes after that, which I also don't like. I would need something that would change animation speed to match loading of content exactly..

Here is the code:

```
<?php if($_SERVER["HTTP_X_PJAX"]): ?>
  <div id="main">first body</div>
<?php else: ?>
  <html>
  <head>
  <script src="http://pjax.heroku.com/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="http://pjax.heroku.com/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
  <script src="http://pjax.heroku.com/jquery.pjax.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
     $(function() {
      $('a').pjax('#main');
        $('#main').bind('pjax:start', function() {
        $('#main').animate({
          height: 'hide',
          opacity: 'hide'
        }, 'fast')
      }).bind('pjax:end', function() {
        $('#main').animate({
          height: 'show',
          opacity: 'show'
         }, 'slow')
      });
    });
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
<?php
  $header = "this is header
  <br/> <a href='test2.php' data-pjax='main'>GO</a>";
  $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
  $footer = "this is first footer";
  echo "$header<br/>$date<br /><div id='main'>first body</div><br />$footer";
?>
  </body>
  </html>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Here is also the link so you can see what I mean:
http://www.bluereservations.com/pjax.php

Comment: I've seen the text bolding myself during animation. It seems to occur for me when I have a 3d transform on an ancestor of that text element. Also, it seems to be webkit browsers that exhibit this! Haven't found a work around though! :(

Comment: i don't have anything on that element.. i even tried with adding font weight normal style, but it doesn't work..